# How can I set animation effect while drag and drop row in NSTableView in Xamarin.Mac

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.mac

I can able to reordering row i.e drag and drop from one index position to another index position in NSTableView in mac but I am not able to get any effect while dragging and dropping row. How can I set any styling for feel to rows are reordering. I have using three overriden methods in TableViewDataSource for rows reordering i.e 1.WriteRows 2.ValidateDrop 3.AcceptDrop. Please suggest any idea, Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can do a `UITableView.MoveRow` in your `AcceptDrop` method and extended the duration of the visual move between rows via an `NSAnimationContext`:

Note: This does **not** reorder the data in the datasource, if preserving the user's new data order is required, you will have to manually reorder that data so a `UITableView.ReloadData` will show the correct order.

```
public override bool AcceptDrop(NSTableView tableView, NSDraggingInfo info, nint row, NSTableViewDropOperation dropOperation)
{
    var rowData = info.DraggingPasteboard.GetDataForType(typeof(Product).FullName);
    if (rowData == null)
        return false;
    var dataArray = NSKeyedUnarchiver.UnarchiveObject(rowData) as NSIndexSet;

    NSAnimationContext.BeginGrouping();
    NSAnimationContext.CurrentContext.Duration = 1;
    foreach (var originalIndex in dataArray.ToArray())
    {
        tableView.MoveRow((nint)originalIndex, row);
    }
    NSAnimationContext.EndGrouping();

    return true;
}
```